# Override models with a Minecraft bukkit/spigot plugin?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I want to make a plugin that allows players to customize their armor models and textures. I want other players on the server be able to see those customizations.

Since I've never done texture overriding in plugins, I have no clue on whether this is possible, and I've been unable to find anything related online. I know you can make blocks look like other blocks, but nothing about armor.

Do I have to send online players a packet, or is there some other way of doing it? If this is possible, is there a place documenting about how to do this?

Comment: You could make a server-side texture pack which is sent to the client.

Comment: @Xiddoc that will make it so only the client can see their own customization, and custom models are also currently impossible with resource packs.  Good idea, but not really what I’m looking for.

Comment: First of all- what do you mean by 'custom models'? Second, everyone on the server would see the client's customization as everyone would have the same custom texture pack (After you send it to them from the server).

Comment: @Xiddoc when I mean custom models, I mean making an armor piece 3D without removing the normal version of it, like what you can do with items. Instead of a texture, it’s a 3D model. Although custom entity models might not be possible in any way, as I’ve heard the models are hard-coded into the client. Now, resource packs do not have the capability to have multiple textures for the same armor. So players would see their customization on all armor of that kind. Making it a retexture, instead of a customization. I was hoping there is a way to retexture armor under conditions with a plugin.

Comment: It is impossible to do this if it is hardcoded into the client. If you want to have efficient code, I'd recommend trying Forge, as I recall that it's the way that most mods are written. If you can't / don't want to use Forge, then you could try to use invisible Armor Stands which teleport to the player at all times to replicate a "new armor model". I haven't done it myself, nor do I know how smooth it will run (given that you will be teleporting a large amount of entities at the same time), but it's the best vanilla implementation that I can think of.

Comment: @Xiddoc forge is not something I will be using, as well the server runs on 1.17 and forge for 1.17 isn’t released yet. Teleporting armor stands I don’t think will look great as the armor will lag behind the player.  Besides customizing the models is less important than retexturing.  If remodeling won’t work and retexturing will, that is fine.

Comment: I finally figured it out by searching on Google. The tutorial is a bit too long for me to simplify into a concise answer, but you can [watch the tutorial yourself](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QLk5MbfGls) to see how to do it. If the video link gets removed in the future, just search "custom leather armor texture minecraft" on YouTube and you'll find boatloads of tutorials which explain how to do it in detail.

Comment: @Xiddoc I think this requires optifine or some other client mod. So I don’t think this will work, since I want it to work with regular Minecraft.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, there are a few ways of going about doing this.

The first is using [Forge](https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted/). Forge has a lot of nice APIs built to help make new mods and items, textures, and models. This makes it perfect for your task, and makes it very simple as you don't need to mess with small technicalities such as packets or such.

However, you also stated that you can't use Forge (only vanilla Minecraft/Spigot APIs). If you want to remodel armor in vanilla Minecraft, another solution could be to use invisible Armor Stands holding/wearing blocks in order to replicate a remodel, and constantly teleport these armor stands to the player. [Here](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/creating-creatures-with-armor-stands.182157/) is a thread explaining how to make a "custom mob" with invisible Armor Stands, you can use this as a base for making a new armor model, then set up an event which teleports the Armor Stands to the player if the player moves (using the `PlayerMoveEvent` event).

Regarding retexturing, you could use [a resource pack which changes the textures of specific armor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QLk5MbfGls) by certain filters (such as the armor item's name). The downside of this is that it requires Optifine, although I'd argue that since Optifine is used in just about every Minecraft client, it's worth using this option. You also noted that you want this to work with the vanilla Minecraft client, although I will point out that Optifine has already [released updates for the latest versions](https://optifine.net/adloadx?f=preview_OptiFine_1.17.1_HD_U_G9_pre32.jar) (such as 1.17, which is what you said you want to play on).

All this information brings me to the summary:
*If you want to make custom armor textures or models in vanilla Minecraft (while keeping the default armor textures as well), then there is no other way than teleporting invisible Armor Stands.*